# Google Storage - signed url Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using the google cloud nodejs storage library to upload some images to cloud storage. This all works fine. I'm then trying to generate a signed URL immediately after uploading the file, using the same storage object that uploaded the file in the first place but I receive the following error:

```
Request had insufficient authentication scopes
```

I'm not sure why this would be happening if it's all linked to the same service account that uploaded in the first place. (For what it's worth it's a firebase app).

The code is below:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
storage = new Storage();
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(event.file.pathName, {
                    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
                    gzip: true,
                    destination: gcsname,
                    metadata: {
                      // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
                      // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
                      // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
                      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'

                    },
                  }).then(result => {
                      let url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${gcsname}`;


                          const options = {
                            action: 'read',
                            expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60, // one hour
                          };

                          // Get a signed URL for the file

                          storage.bucket(bucketName).file(gcsname).getSignedUrl(options).then(result => {
                              console.log("generated signed url", result);

                          }).catch(err => {
                            console.log("err occurred", err)

                          })

                      })
```

The bucket itself isn't public and neither are the objects, but it's my understanding that I should still be able to generate a signed url. The app itself is running on GCP compute engine, hence not passing any options to the `new Storage()` - passing options in fact also makes the upload fail.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What rights does the service account have?

Comment: Storage admin I believe

Comment: Just confirmed the service account that the compute engine instance is running under has full storage rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited amount of information I have, here's a few things that you could be missing based on the error you are receiving:

1. The [Identity and Access Management (IAM) API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/iam.googleapis.com) must be enabled for the project
2. The Compute Engine service account needs the iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission, available to the "Service Account Token Creator" role.

Additionally, you can find more documentation regarding the topic here.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually